# AWS Lambda - separate/protected binary store, so devs don't have to share binary files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to wrap my head around how using custom binaries with Lambda works. Since you have to upload the code bundle in a ZIP file (or pull it from S3), that means this action overwrites whatever you currently have in place. So let's say I have a folder structure like this in said ZIP file:

```
myFunc/
  index.js
  bin/
  node_modules/
```

And in the `bin` folder are a couple of binary executables. This means all the developers on the team would have to have access to these binaries, and every time even the smallest code change was made to `index.js`, they would have to ZIP this up with the binaries every time and upload the bundle.

Is there not some way in Lambda to specify some sort of separate cache/store where binaries can be kept, independently of the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you use a build server for - anybody pushes a code change, and a bundle is created automatically within seconds. Even better, the bundle can be pushed through a test [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery#Relationship_to_continuous_deployment) until it reaches production (via the AWS API using for example [boto](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.update_function_code)) a few minutes later.

You could possibly store binaries somewhere like S3 for access by the Lambda, but then you have a *massive* problem of version controlling them. Much easier (and safer) to create a complete bundle with absolutely everything the program needs. Additional benefits:

- You can be absolutely certain of which exact code was involved in handling a particular request, making debugging much easier.
- Developers can download the whole bundle and run it without having to establish a connection to the binary repository.
- The bundle can be migrated to another service with minimal effort.

Comment: So the necessary binaries are stored on the CD server. Dev makes a code change, pushes it, CD server transpiles or whatever it needs to do, packages up a ZIP file along with the binaries, and then.... ? How does that get automatically updated in the Lambda function?

Comment: @ffxsam and then it updates the lambda function on AWS either via their CLI or SDK.

Comment: You need to use the AWS API. There's plenty of documentation around, and tools for every language and platform.

Comment: Or a script could just use `aws-cli` to upload the function code.